# Checkbox hierarchy with dynamic json using ngx-treeview

Tags: typescript, angular7, ngx-treeview

I am trying to achieving [ngx-treeview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-treeview/v/6.0.2) kind UI using my dynamic json response. But It gives me error like below:

[not assignable to type treeitem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd4pl.png)

Below is my json :

```
   {
  "id": "2",
  "parentId": "0",
  "value": "banks",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "54",
      "parentId": "2",
      "value": "MasterCard",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "5",
          "parentId": "54",
          "value": "US branch",
          "children": [],
          "level": 2,
          "deletable": false
        },
        {
          "id": "56",
          "parentId": "UK branch",
          "value": "Cognition",
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "51",
              "parentId": "56",
              "value": "Manager dept",
              "children": [],
              "level": 3,
              "deletable": false
            },
            {
              "id": "52",
              "parentId": "56",
              "value": "Technical dept",
              "children": [],
              "level": 3,
              "deletable": false
            }
          ],
          "level": 2,
          "deletable": false
        }
      ],
      "level": 1,
      "deletable": false
    },
    {
      "id": "74",
      "parentId": "2",
      "value": "e-Zest Banglore",
      "children": [],
      "level": 1,
      "deletable": true
    },
    {
      "id": "75",
      "parentId": "2",
      "value": "Axis",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "77",
          "parentId": "75",
          "value": "Axis india",
          "children": [],
          "level": 2,
          "deletable": false
        }
      ],
      "level": 1,
      "deletable": false
    }
  ],
  "level": 0,
  "deletable": false
}
```

my component.ts:

```
  import { TreeviewItem, TreeviewConfig } from 'ngx-treeview';
  ...
  dropdownEnabled = true;
  items: TreeviewItem[];
  values: number[];
  config = TreeviewConfig.create({
    hasAllCheckBox: true,
    hasFilter: false,
    hasCollapseExpand: true,
    decoupleChildFromParent: false,
    maxHeight: 250
  });

  ngOninit(){
    this.items = this.getHierarchcategories();
  }

  getHierarchcategories(): TreeviewItem[] {
        const companydata = new TreeviewItem({
      {
        "id": "2",
        "parentId": "0",
        "value": "e-Zest",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "54",
            "parentId": "2",
            "value": "MasterCard",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "5",
                "parentId": "54",
                "value": "hi",
                "children": [],
                "level": 2,
                "deletable": false
              },
              {
                "id": "56",
                "parentId": "54",
                "value": "Cognition",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "id": "51",
                    "parentId": "56",
                    "value": "Technotica 2",
                    "children": [],
                    "level": 3,
                    "deletable": false
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "52",
                    "parentId": "56",
                    "value": "Techno3",
                    "children": [],
                    "level": 3,
                    "deletable": false
                  }
                ],
                "level": 2,
                "deletable": false
              }
            ],
            "level": 1,
            "deletable": false
          },
          {
            "id": "74",
            "parentId": "2",
            "value": "e-Zest Banglore",
            "children": [],
            "level": 1,
            "deletable": true
          },
          {
            "id": "75",
            "parentId": "2",
            "value": "e-Zest Pune",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "77",
                "parentId": "75",
                "value": "e-Zest Hinjewdi",
                "children": [],
                "level": 2,
                "deletable": false
              }
            ],
            "level": 1,
            "deletable": false
          }
        ],
        "level": 0,
        "deletable": false
      }
    });

    return [companydata];
  }
```

my component.html is like below:

```
  <ngx-treeview
    [config]="config"
    [items]="items"
  >
      </ngx-treeview>
```

by running this code I am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZvRz.png) error. Can we achieve tree view with this kind of json format? Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

The constructor `new TreeViewItem(item)` requires that the parameter `item` fulfills the interface `TreeItem`;  That interface is:

```
interface TreeItem {
    text: string;
    value: any;
    disabled?: boolean;
    checked?: boolean;
    collapsed?: boolean;
    children?: TreeItem[];
}
```

([source](https://github.com/leovo2708/ngx-treeview/blob/5b4591664b385a4838ca0ffa65bfc6bbb7cc299b/projects/ngx-treeview/src/lib/models/treeview-item.ts))

There are two things going wrong here, one easier to fix than the other.  The easy one is that your JSON contains extra properties which are not part of the `TreeItem` interface.  This is the source of the `property id does not exist on interface TreeItem` error in your screenshot.

Extra properties are only a problem when the object is created within the function call.  So you can define your JSON separately and that error will go away.

```
 const myJson = { /** your data here **/ }; 
 const companydata = new TreeviewItem(myJson);
```

Unfortunately now you get the second error, which is the more difficult one.  Interface `TreeItem` requires that each item in the tree have a property `value`, which it does, and also have a property `text`, which you don't have.  In order to be passed into the `TreeviewItem` constructor, you will need to map your JSON such that it has this missing `{text: string}` property on each node.